# Switch to a different workspace while using a VM

Tags: unity, workspaces, vmware

I'm using Vmware Workstation 8 on an Ubuntu 11.10 host.

Is there a way I can exclude certain inputs from going to the virtual machine and instead direct those inputs to the host?

Ideally what I'd like to do is be able to use the control+alt+arrow key shortcut to move to a different workspace even if I am focused in a virtual machine.

Does anyone know a way I can accomplish this?

Thanks!!

(I'm using Unity, but I'd switch to gnome-shell or kde or whatever for this feature if necessary!)

Answer (score 7):

One way of achieving this is by changing the shortcut that VMware Workstation uses to escape from the VM (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> by default). In VMware Workstation go to *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Hot keys* and pick a different combination. This will allow you to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow key</kbd> to switch workspaces.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone is using Ubuntu 20.04, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>  or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>.

Comment: The workspaces in Ubuntu 20.04 are vertical. Perhaps you mean up and down arrows instead of left and right.