# Workspace switcher keyboard shortcuts for left and right workspaces not responding

Tags: shortcut-keys, workspaces, vmware-player

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit (running as a VM on VMWare Player). The keyboard shortcut for Workspace switcher indicates that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ arrow keys switches to the desired workspace.

[image]

While this works for Up/Down arows, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ Left/Right doesn't seem to work - the switcher doesn't move to the desired workspace.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Are you running under VMWare Player? Because I have this problem as well, and `unity --reset` doesn't fit it.

Comment: @SCdF yes, I'm running it under VMWare Player!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So as noted in Sathya's comment, he is running under Vmware.

The reason this doesn't work is because VMware Player is taking control of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, because that's the key combination it uses to "break out" of the VM.

There are two ways you can fix this:

### Override

There is an escape override built into VMware which overrides the breakout combination, by tapping <kbd>Space</kbd> while holding down the breakout combination, before hitting your desired key So for example, if you wanted to go to the right workspace you would hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, tap <kbd>Space</kbd> and then tap <kbd>Right</kbd>.

### Change the Combination

Change the breakout combination. To do this, edit preferences.ini (in Windows 7 it's in `C:\Users\$YOUR_USERNAME$\AppData\Roaming\VMware`, if you can't find it search) and add:

```
pref.hotkey.shift = "true"
pref.hotkey.alt = "true"
pref.hotkey.control = "true"
```

This remaps the breakout combination to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Before you say anything, yes, I realise that this is also used in Ubuntu, to move windows between workspaces. Unfortunately, that is the best I've been able to come up with so far. You are *supposed* to be able to be as specific as left or right control, but they don't work for me, leftControl etc just maps back to both.

References:

- http://communities.vmware.com/message/353101#353101
- http://sanbarrow.com/vmx/vmx-preferences-ini.html

Comment: Or you can add Win key to that combination and it will not interfere with normal shortcuts - http://askubuntu.com/a/106612/104730